# Information don't post in database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I try to implement an sign in form based on webcam image, apparently, i don't errors in code, but information don't posted in database.

Here is my index with php code for insert information in database:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['desc'])) {
    if (!isset($_POST['iscorrect']) || $_POST['iscorrect'] == "") {
        echo "Sorry, important data to submit your question is missing. Please press back in your browser and try again and make sure you select a correct answer for the question.";
        exit();
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['type']) || $_POST['type'] == "") {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error parsing the form. Please press back in your browser and try again";
        exit();
    }
    require_once("scripts/connect_db.php");
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
    $name = strip_tags($name);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
        $name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $image = base64_encode(
                file_get_contents(
                        $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']
                )
        );
    }
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (name,email,image) VALUES ('$name', '$email','$image')")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    header('location: index.php?msg=' . $msg . '');
    $msg = 'merge';
}
?>      
<?php
$msg = "";
if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    $msg = $_GET['msg'];
}
?>   
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Licenta Ionut</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
        <!-- font files  -->
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!-- /font files  -->
        <!-- css files -->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />
        <link href="web.js" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="web.js"></script>
        <!-- /css files -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="color:#06F;"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
        <h1>LogIn with Webcam Password</h1>
        <div class="log">
            <div class="content1">
                <h2>Sign In Form</h2>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="userid" value="USERNAME" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                    this.value = 'USERNAME';
                                }">
                    <input type="password" name="psw" value="PASSWORD" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                    this.value = 'PASSWORD';}">
                    <div class="button-row">
                        <input type="submit" class="sign-in" value="Sign In">
                        <input type="reset" class="reset" value="Reset">
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="content2">
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <form action="index.php", name="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Nume">
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="EmailAdress">
                    <br>

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.js"></script>
                    <script language="JavaScript">
        document.write(webcam.get_html(320, 240));
                    </script>
                    <div class="button-row">
                        <input class="sign-in"  type=button value="Configure" onClick="webcam.configure()" class="shiva">
                        <input class="reset" type="submit" value="Register" id="image" onClick="take_snapshot()" class="shiva">
                    </div>
                </form>    
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the script for connection to database:

```
    <?php 

$db_host = "localhost";
// Place the username for the MySQL database here
$db_username = "Ionut"; 
// Place the password for the MySQL database here
$db_pass = "1993"; 
// Place the name for the MySQL database here
$db_name = "users";

// Run the connection here 
$connection=mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die (mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_select_db($connection,"$db_name") or die ("no database");
?>
```

I don't find error in code and i need your advice/help!

Thank you for interest about my problem!

Comment: Put `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your PHP script. Does it display any errors?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if $_POST['desc']` actually exists? plus, you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). You are incorrectly using the escape calls (**NEVER** manipulate the escaped string afterwards - you risk UNDOING the escaping). plus, you never bother checking if the upload actually succeeded. just because there's info in $_FILES means nothing - failed uploads will STILL put data into $_FILES.

Comment: @NanaPartykar: pointless. using quotes like that is simply cargo-cult programming, but it doesn't change the values.

Comment: From Which Page `$_POST['desc']` is coming? Please provide more details. In your given code. No Such `desc` is written.

Comment: A small thing I noticed... `<input class="sign-in"  type=button value="Configure" onClick="webcam.configure()" class="shiva">` should be `<input class="sign-in"  type="button" value="Configure" onClick="webcam.configure()" class="shiva">`

Comment: Thank for reply! I trying another possibility... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve a problem like this, break the problem into parts.

(1) First, what is the PHP file receiving? At the top of the PHP file, insert:

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
    die('-----------------------------------');
```

(2) If that doesn't reveal the problem, next step is to duplicate the PHP file and in the second copy, HARD CODE the information you will be submitting at the top (replacing the PHP data that would normally be submitted):

```
<?php
    $_POST['desc'] = 'TEST - Description';
    $_POST['iscorrect'] = 'what it should be';
    $_POST['type'] = 'TEST - Type';
    etc
```

Then, run that modified file and see if the data is submitted.

(3) If that doesn't reveal the problem, keep working with the duplicate PHP file and add `echo` statements at various places to see where the file is breaking. For example:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
echo 'HERE 01';
$name = strip_tags($name);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);
$email = strip_tags($email);
echo 'HERE 02';
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image = base64_encode(
            file_get_contents(
                    $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']
            )
    );
}
echo 'HERE 03';
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO users (name,email,image) VALUES ('$name', '$email','$image')")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
echo 'HERE 04: $sql = ' .$sql;
```

Comment: really thank you for advice! It's very useful. I hope to solve my problem. Thank you again! :)